# Using "And" operator comparing three variables

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
if (dr["programmeCode"].ToString() == (combo_Programme.ToString())) &= (dr["Actions_ProgrammeDerivedCode"].ToString()) = null;
```

Can anyone help and explain why my "And" expression "&=" (or "&&") will not work in the above expression ?

Comment: Do you mean 
`(dr["Actions_ProgrammeDerivedCode"].ToString()) == null { ... } `

Comment: Yes - I received a discard message for some reason

Comment: Very poor help and advice from some members of the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cand do the following..

```
if (dr["programmeCode"].ToString() == combo_Programme.ToString() 
        && string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Actions_ProgrammeDerivedCode"].ToString()))
{
}
```

Comment: Good use of `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do and neither is the computer.  I am assuming your code is all part of the logical statement.

The `&=` assigns a value to the variable on the left of it.  So in your case, you would be trying to assign (dr["Actions_ProgrammeDerivedCode"].ToString() to the if statement!

You meant to use the `&&` operator, then you might note that your parentheses exclude the statement from the logical test.  You need to add more parentheses and change the `= null` to `== null` or it will also try to assign:

```
if ((dr["programmeCode"].ToString() == combo_Programme.ToString())
   && (dr["Actions_ProgrammeDerivedCode"].ToString() == null)) { 
       do something...
   }
```

Here is a link to some helpful documentation on variable assignment:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx

Here is a link to some helpful documentation on if statements:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx

Comment: Both solutions work admirably.  This site is best by far.